# Find the value or prove that it's impossible

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, factorial

Let there be 4 integers $w,x,y,n$ belonging to $ℤ+$ such that $w,x,y \geq n$ and $n \gt 2$. Find the value of $w$ in terms of $x, y, n$ or prove that it's impossible if $ x \neq y $ and

$\frac{w!}{(w-n)!} = \frac{x!}{(x-n)!} + \frac{y!}{(y-n)!}$

I faced this problem while trying to solve a probability problem, if I have a box called $A$ with $x+y$ balls and a box $B$ with $x$ white balls and $y$ black balls, find the number of white balls in $A$ such that the probability you pick out $n$ balls either all white or black from $B$ is equal to the probability you pick out $n$ white balls from $A$. It boiled down to the equation I wrote above, and after some analysis (the consecutive nature of the integers etc.) it seemed impossible for $n$ to be greater than 2. I tried proving it, and was thinking in the direction of prime factors & mod. Also, I noticed the equation is equivalent to $^w P_n$ = $^x P_n$ + $^y P_n$ as well, but thinking in that direction didn't really prove fruitful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: added more context

Comment: If you divide through by $n!$ you get ${w\choose n}={x\choose n}+{y\choose n}$. A solution is $(w,x,y,n)=(17,10,16,3)$. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27305/a-binomial-generalization-of-the-flt-bombieris-napkin-problem

Comment: thank you @GerryMyerson, that answers my question.